# Filtering multiple fields from a form to open a report

Tags: vba, ms-access, filtering, combinators

MS Access Database: I have a report that I want to open from a form with multiple filter fields.  Each filter works fine when used individually.  They do not work when I try combining them.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Lessons Learned", acViewReport, , "Customer = '" & CustName & "'"

DoCmd.OpenReport "Lessons Learned", acViewReport, , "Phase = '" & ProjectPhase & "'"
```

When I try combining them with AND, I get errors

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Lessons Learned", acViewReport, , "Phase = '" &ProjectPhase&"'" And "[Customer] = " & CustName& "'"
```

I have been trying to resolve this for weeks.  Thank you

Comment: `"Phase = '" & ProjectPhase & "' AND [Customer] = '" & CustName & "'"`

Comment: General rule: static text within quote marks, concatenate variables and don't forget spaces. Would be better to filter on numeric key fields instead of text.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you.  How can I make it skip a field if it is empty?  I have about 5 fields that I am trying to combine.